# Using same v-model to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have one dropdown which is set v-model="compose.Recipient".

According to the "compose.Recipient", i need to show-up another drop-down as following

```
<div class="form-group" v-if="compose.Recipient==2" title="<?=$this->lang->line('SELECTCLASS')?>">
      <select v-model="compose.RecipientID" >
           <option v-for="value in a" v-bind:value="value"><?=$this->lang->line('CLASS')?> {{value}}</option>
      </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" v-else-if="compose.Recipient==3" title="<?=$this->lang->line('SELECTGRADE')?>">
      <select v-model="compose.RecipientID" >
           <option v-for="value in b" v-bind:value="value"><?=$this->lang->line('GRADE')?> {{value}}</option>
      </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" v-else-if="compose.Recipient==4" title="<?=$this->lang->line('SELECTBUS')?>">
      <select v-model="compose.RecipientID" >
           <option v-for="value in c" v-bind:value="value"><?=$this->lang->line('BUS')?> {{value}}</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

It's not working because of v-if, if i use v-show it's working.

I'm using same  `v-model="compose.RecipientID"` to all dropdowns therefore i could not be able to use v-show instead of v-if.

How to solve it?

Advanced Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using three different `select` elements, create a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) that represents the source of the `select`.  That computed function will look at `compose.Recipient` and return either `a`, `b`, or `c`.  Use that computed as the source for the `v-for` (in a single `select`).

This way you're only binding a single item to `compose.RecipientID` and you don't have to worry about showing/hiding different `select` elements.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
In case to use computed property, i have two issues
1) I need to $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh') run it after return the value inorder to update the values to dropdown.
2) Dynamically bind the title and prefix to each dropdown.


I mean in case of "compose.Recipient==2", need to bind 

   title as `title="<?=$this->lang->line('SELECTCLASS')?>"`
   prefix as  `<?=$this->lang->line('CLASS')?>`

Comment: I have edited the questions with title and prefix.Please review it